# Tag proposal: personalization

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I am interested in the topic of personalizing my phone, and I imagine other users are also. The tag doesn’t exist currently, and due to lack of points, I cannot create it.

customization may be a synonym, but the category, personalization, exists in google play store. That is why I think the term should be considered for  tag creation.

user-interface, interface, could be related tags, unfortunately those don’t exist either currently.

Comment: [user-interface](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) is an existing tag. You appear to have used it on your question.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO we don't need a separate tag for that, as [customization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) (which we already have) covers that perfectly. For ease of transition, we might consider creating `personalization` as synonym to this – which also had the pro guiding people looking for the right tag, but not as a separate tag.

Our tags do not resemble categories in Google Playstore (one could also point at Google asking to create a "custom-rom", "rooting", or "adblock" category, referencing ASE having a tag for it – I bet no chances for #3 there :)

Comment: I've added the synonym, good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewRead!